# making responsive when my template is ready which is not responsive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can i turn my template into responsive one without doing much editing?

i have already designed my template but it is not responsive now if i sit to make it responsive (all webpages) it will take me the same amount of time when it did while i started it designing.

I have made my template using htm5 and css3.

i have also used jquery for functions.

Can i turn my template into responsive one without doing much editing?

i have already designed my template but it is not responsive now if i sit to make it responsive (all webpages) it will take me the same amount of time when it did while i started it designing.

I have made my template using htm5 and css3.

i have also used jquery for functions.

Comment: You can always use **[`twitter-bootstrap`](http://getbootstrap.com/)** if you want to avoid overhead.

Comment: If you don't want to use bootstrap have a look at the @media queries

Comment: What you ask is absolutely possible but that will take extra time and effort, as one suggestion is already there to use **bootstrap** which is already responsive ready. but in your case you have to write your own media queries and some js mods as per mobile devices.